# How to add custom directory e.g. phpmyadmin?

Tags: apache2, lamp

As my knowledge about `apache` is minimal. I'd like to let it grow so I'd have more experience with LAMP. My hot question for today is:

***How to add custom directory to webserver? (e.g. phpmyadmin)?***

My goal is to be able to create custom addresses with custom websites within. Let's suppose that I have my custom directory at: `/media/my/web/portal1` and I'd like to load it when client calls

```
http://localhost/myportal1 at webbrowser.
```

Could you give me a list of steps with few words of explanation?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Edit your Apache config file and add an *Alias* Directive. For example, let's use the *default* file.

```
sudo -e /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Make your alias by adding a section within the *VirtualHost* directive:

```
Alias /database/ "/usr/share/php5/phpmyadmin/"
<Directory "/usr/share/php5/phpmyadmin/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Save and restart: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Or for the other reference:

```
sudo -e /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

And the contents...

```
Alias /myportal1/ "/media/my/web/portal1/"
<Directory "/media/my/web/portal1/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    # New directive needed in Apache 2.4.3: 
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Save and restart: `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

Add more directives within the *Directory* directives, such as

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
```

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#directory

That what you were after?

Comment: I think it is sufficient to reload apache after making those changes?

Comment: Thanks Cristopher! That is just what I was looking for! :)

Comment: I added this line insde the <Directory> section to prevent Forbidden errors, hopefully the edit will be accepted soon: Require all granted

Comment: There is no need for appending an ending slash in the alias name. It forces the user to strictly type it to the URL. In such case, Alias /myportal1 other than Alias /myportal1/. Note missing ending slash.

Answer (score 6):

A simpler alternative is to create a soft link from the document root. For example, if the document root is "/var/www" (the default on most Linux systems), then the following command does the trick:

```
sudo ln -s /media/my/web/portal1 /var/www/myportal1
```

This works immediately - you don't even need to reload the Apache server.

Answer (score 1):

Apache is a user in your system, just like you are, except that it cannot login. That means file access is exactly the same for Apache as it is for you. So, first, if Apache should serve a directory in /media/something, then Apache must have access to read it and its files.

Second, to setup a site that uses this directory as its home, you create sites-files, like /etc/apache2/sites-available/your-site. This is part of what's called vhosting. There are two different types; one based on name (the domain name) and one based on IP. The most common setup is to use name-based vhosts. You can read more about that here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/

Comment: Thanks for references. I will definatelly dig into this! :)

Answer (score 0):

So Simple in two lines :

```
sudo ln -s /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

After

just edit the file "phpmyadmin.conf"

```
pico /etc/apache2/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf
```

and change it to 'loool' or whatever :)

```
Alias /loooool /usr/share/phpmyadmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>

SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^ZmEu" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BackDoorBot" bad_bot
SetEnvIfNoCase user-agent "^BlackWidow" bad_bot 
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^BotALot" bad_bot
```

after all of this reload apache :D

```
service apache2 reload
```

tadaaa :D
ciao :)