# how to add a user directory in apache on ubuntu

Tags: apache2

I am new to apache

Want to add a new user directory in addition to root directory i.e /var/www/html

I have gone through this answer before  [How to add custom directory e.g. phpmyadmin?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92069/how-to-add-custom-directory-e-g-phpmyadmin) but unable to figure out exact steps

let that directory be /home/my_username/somefolder/

So that when i type the url: http://localhost/~my_username/somefolder/ , i get the html files in the specified directory.

Please can someone help me in setting up this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
sudo a2enmod userdir
```

to enable `moduserdir` (if it isn't already enabled).

Add

```
UserDir somefolder
```

to your VirtualHost's configuration to set the diectory name to `somefolder` (by default it's `public_html`.

Add something like

```
   <Directory /home/*/somefolder/ >
     Require all granted
     Options +Indexes 
   </Directory>
```

to your VirtualHost's configuration to allow access to the user directories.

Comment: Where do i have to put the above statements? Is it in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf  !!!

Comment: In your Virtualhost conf in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` or where ever it is. Read `/usr/share/doc/apache2/README.Debian.gz` if you don't know about the Debian/Ubuntu way to configure Apache.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the terminal, and enter following bash:

```
        gksu /var/www/html users
        ln /etc/greeter-lightdm/lightdm.conf users
        echo 'users'
        sudo restart lightdm
```

and it might work fine this way.