# How should I give access to a PHP script on a local host-only server?

Tags: 12.04, server, virtualization, apache2.4

I have a 14.02 LTS client and server VM connected using host-only and DHCP. Connectivity between them has been achieved and I can ping each machine from the other. I have LAMP installed and I'm following [this](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-mantis-bug-tracker-on-debian-7-wheezy/) guide to install Mantis Bug Tracker 1.2.19 on my server.

However, I get the following error message when trying to access `var/www/mantis/admin/install.php` on the client machine:
[image: Error screenshot]

I'm fairly inexperienced in GNU-Linux so I'm not sure what the problem might be here. The contents of `var/www/mantis` can be seen here:

[image: mantis directory]

And as seen there, `install.php` does exist, and in the location I tried accessing through the web browser on the client. But I don't think the permissions are set correctly. The tutorial stated to enter the command `chown www-data: -R mantis/`. Is there a better way of doing this?

Any help with this would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: what does entering `192.168.0.100` give you?

Comment: The 'Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page'.

Comment: Have you edited your apache2 for your site to be in allowed list?
such as given in this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/92069/how-to-add-custom-directory-e-g-phpmyadmin
That is, whether you've edited your apache path to some other than /var/www?

Comment: @PauliusŠukys I did not. I tried it there using `sudo -e /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`, then input [this](http://i.imgur.com/keSc51L.png), saved and restarted the server using `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart` but it didn't appear to work. Am I following that correctly? Sorry for my cluelessness.

Comment: The error log can often help by providing more context like the filesystem path it's looking in for the file.  I'm new to Ubuntu, so don't know the exact location, but try `/var/log/httpd/error_log` or `/etc/httpd/logs/error_log`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you can solve this in two ways:

1. If you want to access your website through `192.168.0.100/mantis/admin/install.php` then all you have to do is: `mv /var/www/mantis /var/www/html/`
2. If you want to access your website through a specific alias like  `192.168.0.100/MantisPortal/install.php` then you have to do:

   - `sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/mantis.conf`
   - Copy all the contents from the sample file you uploaded except that you must take the quotes off the directory paths and also don't specify the filename in the directory path.
   - Save that and then do: ´a2ensite /etc/apache2/sites-available/mantis.conf´
   - And now restart apache and you should find your website in `192.168.0.100/MantisPortal/install.php`