# webserver accesses files from another disk

Tags: apache2

I've a root server with 2 disks. Is  there a way to download something of my second drive while apache is installed @ disk 1?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you mount the drive and you include the path as an Alias.
The specific syntax for an Alias for Apache is covered [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92069/how-to-add-custom-directory-e-g-phpmyadmin).
Also do note that the web server is gonna need read permission for the files it is accessing.