# Redirecting url to custom directory

Tags: server, apache2, php

I have a URL https://facebook.****.in, set up to point at a directory /var/www/html/facebook_app. the virtual hosts file for this is /etc/apache2/sites-available/facebook.****.in.conf.

I would like to add a path to the URL which points to another custom directory such that,

```
https://facebook.****.in/apis    ->   /var/www/html/apis
```

I searched this forum and found some solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92069/how-to-add-custom-directory-e-g-phpmyadmin)

But I'm not sure where should i add the alias to? should it be the default.conf? or the facebook.****.in.conf file.

If it is facebook.****.in.conf file, how should i specify the alias? I would like to host it on 443 port for SSL.

facebook.****.in.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName facebook.****.in
    ServerAlias facebook.****.in
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/facebook_app/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName facebook.****.in
    ServerAlias facebook.****.in
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/facebook_app/

    #   SSL Engine Switch:
    #   Enable/Disable SSL for this virtual host.
    SSLEngine on

    #   A self-signed (snakeoil) certificate can be created by installing
    #   the ssl-cert package. See
    #   /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.Debian.gz for more info.
    #   If both key and certificate are stored in the same file, only the
    #   SSLCertificateFile directive is needed.
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/facebook_****_in.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/facebook.****.in.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/facebook.****.in.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>
```

here's the .htaccess file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#When your application folder isn't in the system folder
#This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
#Submitted by: Fabdrol
#Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]



</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
# If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
# can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
# Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I have an index.php file which maps the url parameters to classes and methods.

Comment: Show us your config files, add them to the post.

Comment: added config file. Please have a look. @yaron

Comment: There are several options, first you can use `ProxyPass`, if this is another dir on the same machine you can symlink to it, the first option would probably be `ProxyPass` as explained here (useful for running services on different ports as a unified service): https://confluence.atlassian.com/doc/using-apache-with-mod_proxy-173669.html

Comment: saw it... can i know the symlink method?

Comment: Try this one: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/creating-soft-link-or-symbolic-link/

Comment: Thanx. That works @yaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the Apache `Alias` and `Directory` directives inside both `VirtualHost` sections that you have in your `facebook.****.in.conf` config file so it is enabled for both HTTP and HTTPS connections.

The snippet of configuration that you should add must be something like

```
Alias "/apis" "/var/www/html/apis"
# Now set directory permission 
<Directory "/var/www/html/apis">
     AllowOverride None
     Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks

     <IfVersion < 2.3 >
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
     </IfVersion>
     <IfVersion >= 2.3>
        Require all granted
     </IfVersion>
 </Directory>
```

I think that your Apache Server version is higher than 2.3, so only adding the `Require all granted` statement should be fine without checking for the version. I added it just in case though.

Also, I included some other directives for security and performance purposes. Please find below a quick overview of them

- `AllowOverride None`: it disables using `.htaccess` files into the directory for security and performance purposes. The Apache Software Foundation recommends this configuration setting at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

> "For security and performance reasons, do not set  AllowOverride to anything other than None in your   block. Instead, find (or create) the  block that refers to the directory where you're actually planning to place a .htaccess file."

- `Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks`: the `-Indexes` option will prevent the Web Server (the `mod_autoindex` module concretely) to return a formatted list of the directory when the required URL maps to a directory where there is no a `DirectoryIndex` (e.g. an index.html file). Apart from that, the `+FollowSymLinks` option allows the server to follow symbolic links in this directory. You can get more information about the `Options` statement and other available options in the Apache Web Server official documentation at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options

Also remember to set the correct permission to the `/var/www/html/apis` directory and files for the user that runs the Apache server (`www-data` in Ubuntu by default) and to restart the Apache service for changes to take effect.

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**Update**

You can also include the `DirectoryIndex` directive into the `Directory` block in case you do not have an `index.html` file in that directory (e.g. index.php)

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

It is also possible to specify more than one file. In that case, the first file found will be returned

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

More information about it at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/es/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Comment: This did not solve the issue. It is still picking up the document root as `/var/www/html/facebook_app/` and opening up files in there.

Comment: Also i would need `Allow Override All` to enable htaccess redirection in my codeigniter setup

Comment: The [Alias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) directive allows documents to be stored in the local filesystem other than under the DocumentRoot. I also added quotes to the `Alias` directive in my answer that I missed to include. Could you check it and try again? About `AllowOverride`, you can set it to `All` if you want to, but you can also try to set it to `None` and add the configuration in the htaccess file to the `Directory` block of config. Also remember to restart Apache for changes to be taken into account.

Comment: Tried as you suggested. It still points the document root as `/var/www/html/facebook_app/`

Comment: okay, I just checked... It is directing me to the folder. but due to some .htaccess issue, i'm only able to call the home controller, but not the methods in it. I believe htaccess might not be working.

Comment: solved this issue. wasnt getting redirected to my index.php. Thanx for the help @gongomgra

Comment: Glad to help @cyberrspiritt! You can specify a different index file for a directory using the `DirectoryIndex` directive. I already added it to my answer.